# How do I show date next to time in the panel with gnome-shell?

Tags: time, date, gnome-shell

[image]

I would like to show the date in the bar up the top there (next to the time).  I can not see any obvious way to enable this.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As a regular user run this in a terminal when using GNOME Shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04, this setting no longer seems to apply. Instead, you can click on the clock, go to Time & Date Settings, select the Clock tab, and check options there to show Weekday or Date and Month in the clock. It's a more obvious place to put these settings, but I had already learned the (now broken) gnome-tweak-tool or gsettings approach.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome 2, use `com.canonical.indicator.datetime`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic

Comment: also works on Debian (and also unsing dconf-editor)

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-date true`

Comment: no longer working in 14.10  :(

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-date true`

Comment: still works in Debian Jessie.

Comment: updated answer still working on 16.04 -- this should be the accepted answer, thanks op!

Comment: Doesn't work in 17.04

Comment: The first one work on 17.10 for me. Change showed up instantly.

Comment: The first one works in 18.04. Why this is not part of the Settings leaves me puzzled.

Comment: I agree - not only does this work perfectly in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but one does wonder why it's not a part of the settings. Pop!_OS 18.04 - which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - has the date shown by default... Why not Ubuntu?

Comment: Doesn't work in 18.04

Answer (score 41):

Not an ubuntu user but, if you install gnome-tweak-tool, you'll have a nice gui to adjust things like this.

I'm guessing your install from repo might be something like:

```
apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Gnome Tweak is indeed a necessity for making 11.10 usable. Also, the date setting is under `Shell->Show date in clock`.

Comment: In 14.04, it's now called "Top bar->Show date"

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit and Gnome 3.18.5

Comment: Still works on recent Ubuntu 17.10. I believe this should be the right answer, since it gives you plenty of options to configure your Gnome Desktop distro, and all options is quite well organized.

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool                     
zsh: command not found: gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: @Snowcrash It is now called "gnome-tweaks". Installing gnome-tweak-tool still works, but it's an alias. Ultimately you now run gnome-tweaks instead.

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu 17.10, I found using the `gnome-tweak-tool` to be the most convenient way.

- Install `gnome-tweak-tool` if not already installed.

  ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
  ```
- Start the tool, either from command line, `$ gnome-tweak-tool` or using Dash (`tweak`).
- Select **Top Bar** from left and then make the necessary changes at right under **Clock**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For most people, the command line option supplied by itnet7 is probably the quickest.

However, if you like a GUI, you can use the tool **dconf-editor**.  Simply run "dconf-editor".  It is included by default with many distributions, but should be in the repositories if it isn't installed.

One you've started dconf-editor, follow the tree of settings to: org-gnome-shell-clock

and change the "Show date" checkbox (as shown below), and the seconds display for the clock too, if you like that sort of thing.

[image: dconf-editor settng for panel clock]

**Edit**: This has changed slightly for Ubuntu 12.10. Using dconf-editor, date & time settings are now located under `com-canonical-indicator-appmenu-datetime`.

For GNOME Shell 3.30.2 the key is `org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date`.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 17.04 and there is neither org-gnome-shell nor com-canonical-indicator-appmenu-datetime
Why oh why do devs see a constant need to move things around?

Comment: I found it in 17.10 under com-canonical-indicator-datetime, but changing the setting had no effect.  Using gnome-tweak-tool worked though.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you click on the time in the bar then:

- Click on `Time & Settings`
- Click the `Clock` tab
- In the clock, show:

  - Check `Weekday` and/or `Date and month`

Answer (score 2):

I installed the "Clock override" extension for gnome-shell, which let's you configure how the date and time is displayed. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/

[image: Screenshot: "2018-05-03 14:32"]

Answer (score -1):

REF: How do I show date next to time in the panel with gnome-shell?
Ubuntu 18.04:  The tool "dconf-editor" also works GREAT in 18.04, although the location (in the editor) has changed.
dconf-editor is easily added with the included Ubuntu Software app.
Simply search for "date" with deconf-editor's search feature and turn date "on".

Comment: You should note that the question already has an accepted answer and if you don't have an additional solution for other users for whom the accepted one doesn't work, you should not needlessly answer. If you do, please try to express yourself clearly and describe what to do step by step, so that everybody knows what to do and can try it.