# The Clock on the top bar is gone in 18.04 LTS

Tags: clock

Time is very very important, I love the new version but no clock on the top bar. I checked every setting can not find a way to tuen it on  The date is in the middle but I need the time. I do not want to download more clock windows that I can not see and take up real estate. Any idea of plans to ree instate the clock????

Comment: Potentially this answer satisfies your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/83597/how-do-i-show-date-next-to-time-in-the-panel-with-gnome-shell

Comment: Are you asking about the date ? Because the time (clock) is in the top bar by default. No setting needed for that.

Comment: The clock is now at center of top bar, not at right.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing Gnome Tweak Tool, it has options for this:

[image: gnome tweak top bar settings]

`apt install gnome-tweak-tool` or find it in the software store. (Also it might be named 'Tweak Tool' or something slightly off...)

Comment: The settings are to add date or seconds. This makes me wonder why the OP ask his question as the Time should be there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact situation, but maybe this can help.
In a terminal type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```

`clock-` has different options, just type `clock-` and TAB